# magento sort subcategories alphabetically

Tags: php, magento, helper

I would like to sort alphabetically my subcategories 
I did it by changing the core but if i can do this cleanly .

I'm using :
`$_category->getChildrenCategories();`

In file : 
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php`

In

```
protected function _getChildrenCategoriesBase($category)

       // ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
       ->setOrder('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
```

If someone use helper or an other way.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dhaval Patel and mondev. I fixed it by calling the collection

```
      $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
      $_subcategories = $currentCategory->getCollection();
      $_subcategories->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
          ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
          ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
          ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
          ->addIdFilter($currentCategory->getChildren())
          ->setOrder('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
          ->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<?php 

  $subcats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('1')->getChildren();
  $catIds = explode(',',$subcats );

  $catarray= array();
  foreach($catIds as $catId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
    $catarray[$category->getName()] = $category->getUrl();
  }

  ksort($catarray, SORT_STRING);
?>

<ul>
   <?php foreach($catarray as $catname => $caturl): ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $caturl; ?>"><?php echo $catname ; ?></a>
    </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Dhaval Patel thanks, but i can't use an array because i call an helper to resize subcat images.

Comment: please try this : ->setOrder('name', 'asc');

Answer (score 0):

Two tips:

1. You can rewrite the Resource Model in your local Module and change code in your case.
2. Or create a new Helper Method something like that:

```
 

    $collection = $category->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
            ->setOrder('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
            ->joinUrlRewrite()

    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->load();
    return $collection;
```